# Zero infront of a number like 2031.04

Tags: excel, format

[image]

I want to create an order ID like 2031.04. But at the moment i have the problem, that the zero behind the dot is missing so it looks like that.
I have one cell witzh 2031 and another with n + 1. Then i want wo show these two cells in one with the following format.

```
2031.1
2031.2
...
2031.9
2031.10
```

Can i somehow add a zero in there. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `2031.04` is not the same number as `2031.4`, and they don't mean the same thing.  What is your goal here?

Comment: its the same number. We use comma over here and not dot.

Comment: The part behind the dot gets incremented in another cell and in this cell i just wanna show the fist part "2031" dot the second part "04"

Answer (score 1):

Based on this comment from OP:

> The part behind the dot gets incremented in another cell and in this
>   cell i just wanna show the fist part "`2031`" dot the second part "`04`"

```
= 2031 & "." & <cell reference>
```

Sounds like you could just concatenate it:

[image]

Also, if you want to just statically input the ID, then simply change the cell format from `General` to either `Text` or `Number` *(with two decimals)*

---

**EDIT:**

Starting from D3:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AF3), AF3, AF3 & "." & AG3)
```

Comment: I added an screenshot and hope that makes my problem a bit easier to understand. In column AG Im incrementing the number for every 2030 in column AF. First problem why is there no zero infront of the 1 but infront of the other numbers? I added a Fromat like #0 for column AG. Secondly i add the Column AF and AG in Column D. But the 0 disappears.

Comment: @Kuempsmichi check my edited answer. Also make sure the Column D is in proper format

Comment: Is it possible to upload the file somewhere? Still didn´t manage to fix it :/

Comment: Preferably google drive. Also keep in mind I won't open it if there are any macros/addins included for security reasons